# asp.net, hide <% Page Language, AutoEventWireup and so on... %> at top of aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, hide

I have a email template formatted aspx not htm or html.

So I send a email using this template, then I get a result that I want.

But at top of email, there is a code like

```
"<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" %>"
```

It isn't a big issue but I don't want this to be exposed as my aspx file's name.

This issue can be solved by use combine aspx file(not aspx and aspx.cs).

However it's not a fundamantal solution.

Do you know how hide this string ?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you reading the page content into an email? Could you not just store the relevant HTML part of the page and send that rather than the whole thing. The page directive should not be getting rendered anyway..

Comment: Rather than attaching the .aspx page, could you use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to call the page and attach the resultant HTML instead?

Comment: I send an email using asp.net Mail module. I am trying to find a method sending mail partly.

Comment: I don't have experience that useing webclient, I'll try. But my boss want to make more lightly, so I listen many idea.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem myself.

I'm using asp.net mail module.

And specific aspx file contains email template.

I was got email contents by StreamReader class.

Previous code is below.

```
sr = new StreamReader(filename.aspx);

EmailBody = sr.ReadToEnd();

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(hostname);
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(parameters);

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(message);
```

And now I am using ReadLine Method for not contains First string(<%Page... blah>)

```
sr = new StreamReader(filename.aspx);
EmailFirstString = sr.ReadLine();

EmailBody = sr.ReadToEnd();

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(hostname);
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(parameters);

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(message);
```

So, I get a result that I want. Thank you.